# Self static referential class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been given a task of compiling the C++ legacy code on a new platform. In the process of compiling, I came across the following code...

```
class GLOBALS
{
public:
    static GLOBALS _global;
};
GLOBALS GLOBALS::_global;

class DEF
{
public:
    GLOBALS::GLOBALS _global;
};
```

When I am trying to compile this code, I am getting following error...

```
error: ‘GLOBALS::GLOBALS’ names the constructor, not the type
GLOBALS::GLOBALS _global;
```

I am not getting what this code is trying to achieve here.. Can anyone enlighten me on this? And how they were able to compile the code previously?

Comment: Whilst this code is not compliant even with C++03/98, e.g. [the ancient GCC 4.4.7 accepts it for `std=c++98`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sUijP3VSAS7UVkT8) -> legacy code that use a legacy compiler that had an accepts-invalid bug (that has since been corrected).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this code tries to just have a reference to itself. The `GLOBALS::GLOBALS` doesn't make any sense unless the class was hidden behind another extra namesspace `GLOBALS`. It might just be a bug in this legacy code.

```
class GLOBALS
{
public:
    static GLOBALS _global;
    int dummy = 0;
};
GLOBALS GLOBALS::_global;

class DEF
{
public:
    GLOBALS _global;
};
int main()
{
  DEF x;
  x._global._global._global._global._global._global.dummy = 1;
}
```

The line `GLOBALS GLOBALS::_global;` establishes a base case. So now we can access a `dummy` variable inside the `_global._global._global...` `GLOBALS` object.

Comment: It was not a bug in legacy code, see my answer.

Comment: You're right, it could be a `typedef`. Sadly neither an additional namespace nor a typedef was in OP's code.

Comment: There isn't need for one to be, the name of the class is publicly available inside the class,.

Comment: I get what you're saying now. Indeed gcc 4 really accepted this. Weird weird.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has to do with the notion of [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name)

As far as the class name within the class itself is publicly available, we are able to write something like this

```
std::vector<int>::vector a;
```

Which deduces to `std::vector<int>`, as far as you can write `vector` inside the `vector` class.

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test something;
.....
.....
   typedef some_type Type;
.....
};
```

When we write `Test::Type`, we know we are referring to `some_type`, and when we write `Test::Test`, the fact that typename `Test` is publicly available inside the `class Test` deduces it to just `Test`.
We can write as many as we want

```
template<class T, class U>
struct is_same
{
    static const bool value=false;
};

template<class T>
struct is_same<T,T>
{
   
    static const bool value=true;
};


int main(){
static_assert(is_same<Test::Test::Test::Test, Test>::value);
}
```

And this is very weird that this compiles in gcc 4.4.7;